# ERR trap not called when setting readonly variable

Tags: bash, shell

Script `test.sh`:

```
set -euo pipefail

function _trap_ext
{
    echo '_trap_ext'
}
function _trap_error
{
    echo '_trap_error'
}
trap "_trap_ext" EXIT
trap "_trap_error" ERR

readonly foo='bar'
foo='bar'

echo 'foobar'
```

Output:

```
./test.sh: line 14: foo: readonly variable
_trap_ext
```

The script terminates at line 14 because of the error (`-e` option) but the `_trap_error` function is not called. Why not?

GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu), 4.2.45(1)-release (i586-suse-linux-gnu)

Comment: FWIW I do not have this bug in 4.3.33, but I also don't see anything in the [change log](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) that obviously denotes its fix.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be a bug.  From the man pages:

> **-e**
>   Exit  immediately  if  a  pipeline  (which may consist of a single simple command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL  above), exits with a non-zero status.
>   ...
>   A trap on ERR,  if  set,  is executed before the shell exits.  This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately (see COMMAND ENVIRONMENT above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.

From what the man pages say, it *should* execute the ERR trap.  You can test that it works as expected in other situations by inserting a `false` before the `foo='bar'` statement.

It also appears that bash doesn't call the ERR trap on syntax errors either, so it may be that attempting to overwrite a readonly variable falls into a similar category of errors which skip the ERR trap.  However, that explanation is pure speculation.